# How can I access and change an element in an array with the help of a pointer in Julia?

Tags: arrays, pointers, julia

I have a nested Array and want to repeatedly get the value at a specific location in the array and change it. Is there a way to do this with a pointer to be more compact? I use Julia 1.6.0.

My array looks like this:

```
Q = Array{Array}(undef, 10,10)
for row in 1:10
    for col in 1:10
        Q[row,col] = Array{Array}(undef, 5,5)
        for i in 1:5
            for j in 1:5
                Q[row,col][i,j] = zeros(9)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

My current solution is to set a variable to the array one level above the element and to then change it:

```
tmp = Q[3,3][2,4]
tmp[5] = 1
```

What I would like to have is some way to directly address the element:

```
tmp = Q[3,3][2,4][5]
tmp = 1
```

This doesn't change the array though. I read something auf the `Ref()` function but didn't quite manage to use it for getting/changing the element.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make an array of pointers:

```
julia> a = [Ref(0) for i in 1:2, j in 1:2]
2×2 Matrix{Base.RefValue{Int64}}:
 RefValue{Int64}(0)  RefValue{Int64}(0)
 RefValue{Int64}(0)  RefValue{Int64}(0)
```

Now you can get one element

```
b = a[1,2];
```

You can mutate it:

```
b[] = 600;
```

Now we get back to the array to see the result

```
julia> a
2×2 Matrix{Base.RefValue{Int64}}:
 RefValue{Int64}(0)  RefValue{Int64}(600)
 RefValue{Int64}(0)  RefValue{Int64}(0)
```

You might also wonder how to get the data:

```
julia> getindex.(a)
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 0  600
 0    0
```

For most scenarios this is not a recommended approach to work with data though.
Have a look at `@view`s instead. Here is an equivalent example:

```
julia> c=zeros(Int,2,2)
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 0  0
 0  0

julia> elem = @view c[1,1]
0-dimensional view(::Matrix{Int64}, 1, 1) with eltype Int64:
0

julia> elem .= 999;


julia> c
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 999  0
   0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest I found for what you are looking for is the CartesianIndex. You can build a CartesianIndex once to refer to a particular element in a multidimensional array and use it to access that element. I assume it is more efficient and requires the use of a single object that represents that index.

See https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/interfaces/ for more info.